# Multiple Django projects inadvertently receiving each other's celery tasks

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have five different Django projects all running on one box with one installation of RabbitMQ. I use celery for various tasks. Each project appears to be receiving tasks meant for other projects.

Each codebase has it's own virtual environment where something like the following is run:

```
./manage.py celeryd --concurrency=2 --queues=high_priority
```

The parameters in each settings.py look like the following:

```
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 10
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//'
BROKER_VHOST = 'specific_app_name'
```

I'm seeing tracebacks that make me think apps are receiving each other's messages when they shouldn't be:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../.virtualenvs/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 556, in _receive_callback
    decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
  File "/home/.../.virtualenvs/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 147, in decode
    self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
  File "/home/.../.virtualenvs/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 187, in decode
    return decode(data)
  File "/home/.../.virtualenvs/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 74, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
ImportError: No module named emails.models
```

The `emails.models` module in this case appears in one project but not the others. Yet the others are showing this traceback.

I haven't look at multiple node names or anything like that. Would something like that fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify different queue settings for each of the projects. For example:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    "celery": {
        "exchange": "project1_celery",
        "binding_key": "project1_celery"},
}
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "celery"
```

For the second project you specify exchange and binding_key as `project2_celery` and so on.

The code I posted is for Celery<3.0. If you are using a newer version, it would probably look like the following (I haven't used the new versions myself yet, so I'm not sure):

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue


CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('celery', Exchange('project1_celery'), routing_key='project1_celery'),
)
```

You can read more in the celery docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html

Comment: Thanks Vadily. I name-spaced each queue attribute in each class that extends Task with an app name prefix and added a unique node name to each instance of celeryd launched and it's working nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

Your AMQP settings in `celeryconfig.py` are wrong. You are using:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//'
BROKER_VHOST = 'specific_app_name'
```

The `BROKER_VHOST` parameter is ignored because `BROKER_URL` is present (also it is deprecated). If you want to use virtualhosts (which by the way is the preferred way to solve the problem you presented) you should create a virtualhost for each app and use the following in each app settings:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//specific_app_name'
```

edited: fixed missing /

Answer (score 0):

With multiple django projects sharing the same box, you need to explicitly "namespace" @tasks per project. The error msg returned a namespace of "emails.models", thats not unique to any one project.

For example, if one project is name "project1", and another "project2", just add "name=" parameters to the @task decorators:

```
# project1
# emails.py
@tasks(name=project1.emails.my_email_function, queue=high_priority)
def my_email_function(user_id):
    return [x of x in user_id if spam()]

# project2
# tasks.py
@tasks(name=project2.tasks.my_task_function, queue=high_priority)
def my_task_function(user_id):
    return [x of x in user_id if blahblah()]
```